# D3.js version 6: Loading a CSV and changing Variable types

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am relatively new to D3.js (version 6). I am successfully able to load the following .csv "prices.csv (see github repo at the end):

However I can not change the variable types.

I have used this code:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

var rowConverter = function(d){
    return{
        month: parseDate(d.month),
        price: Number(d.price.trim().slice(1))
    };
}


d3.csv("prices.csv", rowConverter, function(data){

    console.log(data);

});
```

The console log says the month and price variable are still strings:

{month: "1/1/2003", price: "$54"}
month: "1/1/2003"
price: "$54"

Note: I have uploaded the .csv on my github page! https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AhmadMobin/D3-Learning/main/prices.csv

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AhmadMobin/D3-Learning/main/prices.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    month: parseDate(d.month),
    price: Number(d.price.trim().slice(1))
  }
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```