# D3.js version 6: Loading a TSV and changing Variable types

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am relatively new to D3.js (version 6). I am trying to load a local .txt file "data.tsv (see github repo at the end).

Here is what I have tried:

```
var psv=d3.dsvFormat("|");

d3.text("data.txt", function(d){
 var rows= psv.parse(data); 
    
}).then(function(data){
    console.log(rows);
});
```

The console log says: **dataHandlers.js:39 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: rows is not defined**

Note: I have uploaded the .txt on my github page! https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AhmadMobin/D3-Learning/main/data.txt

Thank you so much in advance in helping a newbie on his D3.js journey

Note: I did ask a very similar question on how to load .csv file in which a kind soul did provide me with a solution :) [D3.js version 6: Loading a CSV and changing Variable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66046837/d3-js-version-6-loading-a-csv-and-changing-variable-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a return here:

```
function(d){
    var rows= psv.parse(data);    
}
```

But that's not the issue: not only `d3.text` doesn't accept a row conversion function, even if it did the `rows` variable would never be automagically passed to the promise (only the text itself).

That said, all you need is `d3.dsv`:

```js
d3.dsv("|", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AhmadMobin/D3-Learning/main/data.txt").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much @gerardo Furtado! I was wondering if you can update your code to format the month and price variables. This is what I am trying to do:
       var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");
        month: parseDate(data.month),
        price: Number(data.price.trim().slice(1))

Comment: @AhmadMobin just do as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66048071/5768908) you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full script for completeness to show how I changed the variable type:

```
d3.dsv("|", "data.txt", function(d){
return{
    month: parseDate(d.month),
    price: Number(d.price.trim().slice(1))
}

}).then(function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   
   });

Huge shoutout to @Gerardo Furtado !
```